# Problemas com insert num projeto Android em Java

Tags: java, android

Sou novo como programador Java para Android, estou criando um aplicativo que ele cadastre um email, na imagem abaixo ele vai cadastrar o email em baixo e em cima o usuario irá efetuar o login.

Porém quando tento cadastrar ele gerar um erro no meu método salvar que é o insert na tabela do banco de dados SQlite como mostra abaixo

```
    12-15 20:35:37.375: I/Process(1830): Sending signal. PID: 1830 SIG: 9
12-15 20:35:40.026: E/Trace(1880): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-15 20:35:41.376: D/gralloc_goldfish(1880): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-15 20:37:52.375: D/AndroidRuntime(1880): Shutting down VM
12-15 20:37:52.375: W/dalvikvm(1880): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at com.example.projetologin.repositorio.RepositorioUsuario.salvar(RepositorioUsuario.java:42)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at com.example.projetologin.repositorio.RepositorioUsuario.salvar(RepositorioUsuario.java:36)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at com.example.projetologin.xml.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:67)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-15 20:37:52.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1880): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

aqui está o meu projeto no Github

https://github.com/wladyband/CadastroEmail

como faço para corrigir esse erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O seu código não aparece aqui, coloque a sua função salvar e indique qual a linha 25.

Comment: @JorgeB. pq a linha 25?? Você não quis dizer 42? 42 é a resposta pra tudo, esqueceu?

Comment: Enganei-me @Math ;)

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.projetologin.repositorio.RepositorioUsuario.salvar(RepositorioUsuario.java:42)`, sim, 42 é a reposta de tudo hehehe.

Comment: 24 também é um número cabalístico.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na linha 42 do `RepositorioUsuario` na função `salvar`:

```
long id = db.insert(NOME_TABELA, "", valores);
```

Porque falta-lhe inicializar a base de dados, não chega declara-la:

```
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
```

Comment: Desculpe Jorge B você colocou a resposta sendo a solução ou so informou algo que eu já sabia? Não sei que chegou a ler com atenção na minha postagem, mas na minha postagem eu já tinha deixado claro que já sabia aonde estava o problema so não sabia como resolver.

Comment: @wladyband a solução é inicializares o db como te disse na resposta.

Comment: Ok, tudo bem, vou fazer uma pergunta de reflexão! você parou para observar meu projeto no Gitgub https://github.com/wladyband/CadastroEmail se vc for observar meu projeto vai perceber que eu iniciei a variavel db por favor  observe melhor meu projeto.

Comment: @wladyband na classe `RepositorioUsuario` não inicializou não, deverias estar qualquer coisa como `protected SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteDatabase();`

Comment: Jorge B não é possivel inicializar da forma como você orientou porque a classe SQLiteDatabase não contém um construtor, e quando entrei na classe SQLiteDatabase para criar um construtor o eclipse não permite que eu faça alteração na classe SQLiteDatabase. tenta me ajudar por favor Jorge B

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19513/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-wladyband).

Answer (score 0):

O que voce precisa @wladyband é apenas instanciar a sua classe SQLiteHelper e utilizar o método getWriteableDatabase. Vou colocar um exemplo

A classe SQLiteOpenHelper fornece os métodos getReadableDatabase() e getWriteableDatabase() para obter acesso a um objeto SQLiteDatabase; no modo de ler ou escrever.

Basta vc instanciar da seguinte maneira:

```
SQLiteHelper conexao = new SQLiteHelper(ctx);
```

antes do seu db.insert vc utiliza esse metodo:

```
db = conexao.getWritableDatabase();
```

e no seu construtor, coloca assim:

```
public RepositorioUsuario(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

Comment: existe algumas considerações que devo falar, e irei falar com tudo respeito. Não vai adiantar essas sugestões, qualquer sugestão que for colocada não terá efeito esclarecedor se as pessoas que querem me ajudar não baixarem a minha aplicação e testarem o que estão me orientando, se não for feito isso será uma ajuda em vão, como é o caso dessa sugestão, colocar as linhas de código acima não tem nenhum efeito prático, e não funcionou, outra coisa é que acredito que somente irei sozinho tentar encontrar a solução, porque preciso entender como funciona a integração do Java com o banco de dados.

Comment: Mas estou sim esperando alguém que possa dá uma ajuda significativa, e não pense que resolvendo o problema para mim não irei aprender. mas somente terão condições de ajudar de baixarem minha aplicação e testarem.